# Call https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tanent ID}/oauth2/token from sharepoint designer workflow

Tags: oauth, workflow, access-token, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to call 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tanent ID}/oauth2/token' from sharepoint designer workflow, but the http call keeps throwing Bad Request Error.

I created two dictionary for requestHeader and requestContent. but it seems the API accepts content as x-www-form-urlencoded or as text but not as JSON. But passing a request content in dictionary always pass it as JSON and result in a Bad Request.

Please let me know if anyone have tried calling https://login.microsoftonline.com to get access token.

Thanks 
Nidhi

Comment: Can you please check your target url have any extra space ..

Comment: there isnt any sapce.

Answer (score 0):

try with this, works for me:

```
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", appSettings.ClientId),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", appSettings.ClientSecret),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", appSettings.Scope),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", appSettings.GrantType),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("resource", appSettings.Resource)
        };
        string requestUrl = $"{appSettings.UrlApiSharePoint}{appSettings.TenantId}/oauth2/token";

        FormUrlEncodedContent requestContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(requestUrl, requestContent);
```